# Can I install Windows 7 on my Seagate Expansion (External) Harddisk?

Tags: windows-7, installation, external-hard-drive

Well, as you guys must be aware that harddisk prices are at peak these days and I don't want to buy a new harddisk at such an high price, so I am having **Seagate Expansion 2TB** harddisk, any ideas if i can install my windows 7 on that harddisk?

If yes then please tell me some advantages and disadvantages of doing that too.

Comment: You can take the hard drive out of the enclosure, and make it an internal if you want...

Comment: It's still in warranty, 2 1/2 years still left, i dont want my warrant to get void :-)

Comment: Hard drive prices are beginning to drop, if you can wait...http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9222871/Hard_drive_prices_slide_as_Thai_flood_aftermath_subsides

Comment: Good thing I bought a whole bunch of harddrives when Tom's Hardware reported the flood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you the ability to boot from a USB, you can install windows 7 on there, and it will run. It will also have **very slow** I/O than and internal hard drive would.

You will probably want to find a better way to do this, but it can work in a pinch.

Comment: Slower is an understatement.